# Change orientation in android emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I have a problem with the Android emulator, while working in Android Studio.

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (or <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) Android emulator *window* change orientation, BUT android doesn't.

I looked in Android settings -> Display, and "auto-rotate screen" is ON.

Comment: You should include the version your targeting. Also check for duplicate issues and let other people now if you have tried other options.

Comment: Ya, probably it's bug. I'm runing emulator on 4.4.2 version.

Answer (score 6):

*I guess you have already found the answer, but this may seem helpful for future searches.*

**Environment**: Android Studio 1.3.2, Windows 7, emulator for API19 (Android 4.4.2) :
Orientation can be changed using the "7" and "9" buttons of your keyboard's numpad. 
**Num Lock** must be **disabled**.